# update controller scope variable if DOM element class get changed

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to angular js. I can change element class based on scope value. But I want to know how can I change the controller scope value if my dom element class is changed. For example, I want to update my $scope.chain variable if my TD has a chain class.Note: My td class will get change based on some condition.

```
 <td class="chain">xxxxxx</td>
```

Comment: _td class will get change based on some condition_ What conditions and How?

Comment: as far as I know, you cant do that. but there is another and better way of tracking this. who will be changing that class, there must be some code which will be adding/removing the class, that is the place from where you can emit an event, which should be caught by your controller to know about the class change... and then do appropriate changes based on that